# setTimeout return a promise

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function that has 2 parameters:

- parameter 1: a callback function,
- parameter 2: time x (ms)

This function will call the callback function after a period of x ms AND returns a promise.

My code follows. It only prints 'Goodbye' after 1s

```
function doAfter(func, time) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(data) {
      resolve(data);
    }, time);
  });
  return promise;
}

function sayHello() {
  console.log('Hello');
}

function sayGoodbye() {
  console.log('Goodbye');
}

doAfter(sayHello, 1000).then(sayGoodbye);
```

Expected behaviour: wait 1s, then print 'Hello Goodbye'

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve `func()`. `data` is undefined in `setTimeout`

```js
function doAfter(func, time) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(func());
    }, time);
  });
  return promise;
}

function sayHello() {
  console.log('Hello');
}

function sayGoodbye() {
  console.log('Goodbye');
}

doAfter(sayHello, 3000).then(sayGoodbye);
```